# Spring boot mongo time out while connecting with mongo driver

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

While I'm working with spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb. I always got a timeout exception. The log detail is as follows:

Could any body tell me why I always got a timeout? thanks so much.

```
2019-04-01 19:08:50.255  INFO 8336 --- [168.0.101:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 192.168.0.101:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateReadException(InternalStreamConnection.java:530)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:421)

2019-04-01 19:09:15.163 DEBUG 8336 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@4ce3ddaf
2019-04-01 19:09:15.165 ERROR 8336 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=192.168.0.101:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message}, caused by {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out}}]; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=192.168.0.101:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message}, caused by {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out}}]] with root cause

com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=192.168.0.101:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message}, caused by {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out}}]
    at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:167)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.getConnectedClusterDescription(Mongo.java:885)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.createClientSession(Mongo.java:877)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$3.getClientSession(Mongo.java:866)
```

My `application.yml` is and spring boot version is 2.0.8.RELEASE, and here is the content:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: 192.168.0.101
      port: 27017
      username: test
      password: test
      database: test
server:
  port: 8888
management:
  health:
    mongo:
      enabled: false
```

Comment: authentication-database=admin

uri=mongodb://username:password@192.168.0.101:27017

repositories:enabled=true

Comment: You can check it here : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.spring4all</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-plus-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

```
@EnableMongoPlus
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Than you have a bunch of more configuration properties to play around :)

```
spring.data.mongodb.option.min-connection-per-host=0
spring.data.mongodb.option.max-connection-per-host=100
spring.data.mongodb.option.threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier=5
spring.data.mongodb.option.server-selection-timeout=30000
spring.data.mongodb.option.max-wait-time=120000
spring.data.mongodb.option.max-connection-idle-time=0
spring.data.mongodb.option.max-connection-life-time=0
spring.data.mongodb.option.connect-timeout=10000
spring.data.mongodb.option.socket-timeout=0

spring.data.mongodb.option.socket-keep-alive=false
spring.data.mongodb.option.ssl-enabled=false
spring.data.mongodb.option.ssl-invalid-host-name-allowed=false
spring.data.mongodb.option.always-use-m-beans=false

spring.data.mongodb.option.heartbeat-socket-timeout=20000
spring.data.mongodb.option.heartbeat-connect-timeout=20000
spring.data.mongodb.option.min-heartbeat-frequency=500
spring.data.mongodb.option.heartbeat-frequency=10000
spring.data.mongodb.option.local-threshold=15
```

I have not tried it yet... but maybe it's worth a try.

Or look in the the repo how to do it without the dependency in your Project ;)

Comment: I was wondering were you got those sample configuration properties and found this sauce - http://www.programmersought.com/article/1927319190/
It also include other example configurations

Answer (score 0):

It is not a final solution, but you can try a longer timeout.

```
 # The time to wait to establish a connection before timing out, in seconds.
 # (default: 10)
  connect_timeout: 99
```

If it connects successfully after changing the timeout, you should find why it is taking so long to establish a connections and try to fix it.
If even after setting a very long timeout it does not connect you should check your proxy and try to ping the machine where is the mongodb.

Comment: Thank you so mush.sir. But I always didn't understand why My code can connection to the mongo server but can't got a response message from it while my local Pc and the  mongo server can always ping each other. I guess maybe there is something wrong with the mongo server configuration.